# can i Use glassfish 4 as Production server

Tags: production, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

Can I use Glassfish 4.0 which is open source and the production/enterprise glassfish hasn't released yet in Production.

I just did small app using java ee 7, and I want to deploy it in production.

Thanks
Ratna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what are the needs and practices in your organization. The Open Source edition has a final release and is certified as JAVA EE7 compliant. So it's good for production use in a sense. If you keep to standards and best practices, you shouldn’t have any problems.

Don't know how the question with frameworks is...

However if you are in need of support, you're stuck to the Glassfish community/Google/StackOverflow. That's where the Enterprise edition makes a difference - you're essentially paying for the same product (with a little bit of add-ons), but mainly for Oracle's support.